# CSS Floating Height Issues

Tags: css, position, css-float

So I have this page:

http://demo.unlockedmanagement.com/example/floating-issue.html

You will notice 3 items: Details, Attachements, and Description.  Now the issue comes when you expand the Details (just click on the title).  The Attachment text gets thrown under the second ul in the detail content.  The thing is the the Attachments should be on their own line.

I am using the clearfix method to try to fix floating elements not having width described here : http://www.webtoolkit.info/css-clearfix.html : except that mine is only doing a clear: right;.  Now obviously the first ul with is floating left has a higher height than the second ul that is floating right however the height of the parent elements seems to be taking the height of the second ul, not the first one which is bigger.

Anyone see what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: You have the attachment title in the same list as the reporter lists, which is part of a list that is styled to be 50% width and floated right.  This is why it's falling underneath reporter, and not in it's own area.  If you want it to be on the far left, you'll need to pull it from that list and either put it in the left list, or make it a new list with clear: left.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried setting your floating containers to display:inline-table? This should allow the floating elements to layout in relation to their siblings and shift when their surrounding elements grow or shrink in size.

Comment: works, will have to read more of the other values for this option beside block/inline.